# SQL Server 2008 date - client side and server side

Tags: javascript, sql-server, datetime

I have been searching for an answer all over the internet and i haven't found any.

I have to make a data comparison between a date in my table (saved with `gettime()` always  so it will be the server's date format) and a date in my web application. 
I have a date picker which get the date in a format like this `'Sun Nov 11 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)'`. I formated the date to work with an english settings SQL server date and it works. The problem is that if a user from France for example installs the web app, the `gettime()` function will save the date in another format, based on the regional settings.
My questions are:

1. Is there any SQL function which converts a date in format 'Sun Nov 11 2012...' in the server's  format (the type of date from `getdate()` function)? - in case if i send that string date as a parameter for my stored procedure
2. What are your suggestions for solving this?

Thanx a lot:)

Comment: The server doesn't *have* a format, if you're (correctly) storing the value in a `datetime` column. And the answer should always be the same - convert from a string into an appropriate datetime type as early as possible, and rely on infrastructure to deal with translating such types between languages/layers.

Comment: do you really need to return the day (Sun) here?

Comment: Thanx all for the answers. No, i haven't needed the week day, i just needed a datetime format from a date constructed by a period selector plugin, which ends up giving me a data like 'Sun Nov 11...'. I ended up converting the data to the Y-M-D format on the client, then manualy added "23:59:59" to the endTime field in my stored procedure, to search including the period between 00:00:00 and 00:23:59:59. Thanx all for the answers again :)

Answer (score 0):

`YYYY-MM-DD` has always worked for me - use the transact-sql `convert` function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

```
CONVERT(datetime, MyDateColumn, 127) AS UsingConvertTo_ISO8601_WithTimeZone
```

`127` being the format you want